# Como utilizar la misma cookie en dos documentos diferentes? O mejor dicho como conseguir la cookie creada de otro documento?

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

Estoy tratando de guardar un usuario que es introducido en un formulario.

```
<input type="text" id="user" required>
```

Una vez introducido en el html se recoge en un javascript

```
let user = document.getElementById("user").value;
```

Una vez tengo mi usuario, pretendo guardarlo en una cookie para llamarlo en otro diferente documento y usar este usuario.

Por lo tanto creo mi cookie usando esta [API](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), es sencilla de usar debe colocarse el script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Al final del documento html y ya podemos proceder en nuestro archivo javascript a usar la librería.
Es lo mismo que usar las cookies convencionales pero nos saltamos los pasos de crearlas directamente colocamos:

```
Cookies.set("nombre", valor, expiracion)  o   Cookies.get("nombre");
```

Explicado esto ya que necesito usar esta librería de cookies supongo que sería similar al uso de las cookies convencionales para responder a mi pregunta ya que supongo que se guardarán de la misma manera.

Mi pregunta es, si yo creo:

```
Cookies.set("usuario", user,{ expires: 7}); //guardar usuario
```

y quiero llamarlo en otro javascript diferente dentro de mi carpeta de scripts de mi página web, como puedo llevarlo de una página a otra? ya que si lo uso en el mismo js funciona correctamente, pero si intento llamarlo en otro js diferente al que se ha "seteado", el resultado siempre es undefined. Creo que necesito exportar mi cookie de alguna forma o tal vez haya algun modo de hacer que me salga en el otro javascript.

He pensado que tal vez deba colocar un path para que sepa de donde lo llamo pero no tengo muy claro el uso de path ni como sería, segun el manual se utilizaría así:

```
Cookies.set("usuario", user,{ expires: 7, path:''});
```

pero no se si es la solucion que yo necesito, alguien podría explicarme?

Comment: las cookies son objetos que se guardan en el navegador, deberías configurar el path de las cookies al guardarlas y al llamarlas

Comment: como se haría esto? no se muy bien como hacerlo estoy algo perdida, quiero decir debo colocar la ruta de mi anterior documento js y en el nuevo debo hacer algo?

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: estas intentando guardar datos del usuario en una cookie? Nunca se debe almacenar ni transmitir información confidencial o sensible mediante Cookies, ya que todo el mecanismo es inherentemente inseguro.

Comment: Las cookies se usaron una vez para el almacenamiento general del lado del cliente. Si bien esto era legítimo cuando eran la única forma de almacenar datos en el cliente, hoy en día se recomienda preferir las API de almacenamiento modernas. Las cookies se envían con cada solicitud, por lo que pueden empeorar el rendimiento (especialmente para las conexiones de datos móviles). Las APIs modernas para el almacenamiento del cliente son la Web storage API (localStorage y sessionStorage) e IndexedDB

Comment: lo que te recomendaria es cifrar los datos y guardarlos en el localStorage y no necesitarias aregar ninguna cdn, solamente utilizando la api del navegador

Comment: Se que no está bien guardar datos de un usuario en una cookie pero me lo piden para un ejercicio de clase ya que todavia estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117784/discussion-between-enzo-and-winterisback).

Answer (score 1):

```js
//guardar.js
////////////

const boton = document.getElementById("boton");
const valor = document.getElementById("valor");

boton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.cookie = `usuario=${valor.value}`
})

//mostrar.js
////////////

const mostrar = document.getElementById("mostrar")
const lista = document.getElementById("lista")

mostrar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log(document.cookie)
})
```

```html
//index.html
////////////

<input type="text" id="valor" required/>
<button id="boton">
 guardar en la cookie
</button>
<script src="./guardar.js"></script>

//main.html
///////////

<button id="mostrar">
  mostrar cookies
</button>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

es muy seguro que no se muestre correctamente en la consola debido a que no es una pagina como tal, pero este es un ejemplo sin usar librerias externas, simplemente usando la api del navegador, espero que te ayude, saludos.

Comment: tambien hay dos paginas html distintas no se usa siempre la misma es decir se recoge en una pagina con un js y a continuacion en otra pagina html con su codigo js se recogería esta cookie, es decir yo tengo un input en el que introduzco cualquier palabra, es recogido en la api de cookies con cookies.set y a continuacion en otro js que funciona con otra página html recojo la cookie y la muestro aqui. es decir 2 documentos js y dos documentos html

Comment: pues las cookies son muy viejas... y presentan problemas de seguridad... en la practica y en este foro esta pregunta puede estar catalogada como basada en opiniones...

Comment: eso esta claro, @FranciscoNúñez, es simplemente un ejercicio.

Comment: @WinterIsBack eso no estaba en la pregunta, lo editare

Comment: disculpa :') creo que no me habia expresado bien